# Retrieving a single string value when grouping rows in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I'm putting together that would be attempting to group rows together from a set of columns that contain string values. I know I can concatenate columns with string values, but I want to be able to report a single cell value instead of all the values in that group .

Here is an example table and result I'm looking for:

Table:

```
ID_Number       Code    Rating
------------------------------
12345678901112  V       100
12345678901113  V       200
12345678901114  H       320
12345678981112  V       300
12345678981113  V       200
12345699981113  D       700
```

Query so far:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(Ex.ID_Number, 10) AS ID_Number, 
    ???(Ex.Code) AS Code, 
    MAX(Ex.Rating) AS Rating
FROM 
    dbo.Exampletable Ex
GROUP BY 
    LEFT(Ex.ID_Number, 10);
```

Desired results:

```
ID_Number   Code    Rating
---------------------------
1234567890  H       320
1234567898  V       300
1234569998  D       700
```

My current results:

```
ID Number   Code    Rating
---------------------------
1234567890  NULL    320
1234567898  NULL    300
1234569998  NULL    700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the expected result set is to use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT ID_Number, Code, Rating
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10) 
                            ORDER BY Rating DESC) AS rn,
         LEFT(ID_Number,10) AS ID_Number, Code, Rating
  FROM dbo.Exampletable ) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

In MySQL you can use a join to a derived table that contains the already aggregated `Rating` value:

```
SELECT LEFT(t1.ID_Number,10) AS ID_Number,
       t1.Rating, t1.Code
FROM Exampletable AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10) AS ID_Number, MAX(Ex.Rating) AS Rating
  FROM Exampletable 
  GROUP BY LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10)
) AS t2 ON LEFT(t1.ID_Number,10) = t2.ID_Number AND t1.Rating = t2.Rating
```

Comment: Sorry about the MySQL Tag, that was a misclick on the suggested tags area of the post. Thanks for the answers though, i'll see if I can use this answer as well to fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired result, you can join your existing result with existing table by `ID_Number` and `Rating`. To do this, you can use `CTE`. This solution is for `SQL Server`

```
;WITH CTE_Result
AS
(   SELECT 
       LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10) AS ID_Number, 
       MAX(Ex.Rating) AS Rating
    FROM dbo.Exampletable Ex
    GROUP BY LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10)
)

SELECT CR.ID_Number, Ex.Code, CR.Rating
FROM CTE_Result CR
INNER JOIN dbo.Exampletable Ex 
   ON ID_Number = LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10) AND Ex.Rating = CR.Rating
```

**UPDATE for MySQL Solution**

```
SELECT
    CR.ID_Number, Ex.Code, CR.Rating
FROM
(   SELECT 
       LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10) AS ID_Number, 
       MAX(Ex.Rating) AS Rating
    FROM dbo.Exampletable Ex
    GROUP BY LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10)
) CR
INNER JOIN dbo.Exampletable Ex 
   ON ID_Number = LEFT(Ex.ID_Number,10) AND Ex.Rating = CR.Rating
```

Comment: Sorry about the MySQL Tag, that was a misclick on the suggested tags area of the post. Thanks for the answers though, i'll see if I can use the first answer to fix my issue.